# Data from JSON Parsing straight to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I am getting data using json with this code and I need to display it in a tableview with two part code and name the problem is writing it all to an array is taking forever and the array comes back null.  How can I get each returned element as its own tableview cell?  Hundreds of airports are returned.

```
 NSString* path = @"https://api.flightstats.com/flex/airports/rest/v1/json/active?appId=id&appKey=appkey";

NSMutableURLRequest* _request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
[_request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;

NSData* _connectionData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:_request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if(nil != error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
else
{
    NSMutableDictionary* json = nil;

    if(nil != _connectionData)
    {
        json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_connectionData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    }
    if (error || !json)
    {
        NSLog(@"Could not parse loaded json with error:%@", error);
    }
    else
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *routeRes;
        routeRes = [json objectForKey:@"airports"];

        for(NSMutableDictionary *flight in routeRes)
        {
            NSLog(@"ident is %@", [flight objectForKey:@"name"]);
            NSString *code=[json objectForKey:@"fs"];
            NSString *name=[flight objectForKey:@"name"];
            NSLog(@"code %@, name %@", code, name);

            [candyArray addObject:[Candy code:code name:name]];
        }
    }
    _connectionData = nil;
    NSLog(@"connection done");
```

The following is the cellForRowatIndex were nothing is shown

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if ( cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Create a new Candy Object
    Candy *candy = nil;

    // Check to see whether the normal table or search results table is being displayed and set the Candy object from the appropriate array
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        candy = [filteredCandyArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    }
    else
    {
        candy = [candyArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[candy name]];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    return cell;
}
```

This is a sample of what the returned json is

```
{"airports":[{"fs":"CLO","iata":"CLO","icao":"SKCL","name":"Alfonso B. Aragon Airport","city":"Cali","cityCode":"CLO","countryCode":"CO","countryName":"Colombia","regionName":"South America","timeZoneRegionName":"America/Bogota","localTime":"2014-03-31T18:51:58.372","utcOffsetHours":-5.0,"latitude":3.543056,"longitude":-76.381389,"elevationFeet":3162,"classification":3,"active":true,"delayIndexUrl":"https://api.flightstats.com/flex/delayindex/rest/v1/json/airports/CLO?codeType=fs","weatherUrl":"https://api.flightstats.com/flex/weather/rest/v1/json/all/CLO?codeType=fs"}
```

This is the search function:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
```

{

```
// Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.

    // Remove all objects from the filtered search array
[self.filteredCandyArray removeAllObjects];

// Filter the array using NSPredicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@",searchText];
NSArray *tempArray = [airportsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@" text %@", searchText);


filteredCandyArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
NSLog(@"NSLog %@", scope);
```

}

Comment: Some of the 'forever' that it's taking is due to the app blocking the main thread while the request runs.  You'll need to fix that with sendAsnych.  But before doing that, please check that you're getting data back.  NSLog(@"starting"); before sending the request, and NSLog(@"json=%@", json); after the JSON parse.

Comment: Well, you need to give us a clue what the JSON looks like.

Comment: I added it to my post, but the value is being returned in the NSLog(@"code %@, name %@", code, name); I need to figure out how to put that info in the tableview.

Comment: I don't see any real need to have your Candy objects.  Just add the "flight" NSDictionary objects to your NSArray and use them directly.

Comment: The JSON you posted doesn't resemble the JSON you're attempting to disassemble.  I don't see an dictionary containing "airports" anywhere, and the code doesn't acknowledge the existence of an array, when in fact the flights are enclosed in an array.

Comment: apologies I left out the first part of the json

Comment: So your code above is wrong.  It should be getting an NSMutableArray from the "airports" reference.  To the extent that the code above works, it's only because the logic for an iterator is generic and doesn't care whether it's a dictionary or array being iterated on.

Comment: But note that you don't even need that loop -- just assign "routeRes" to "candyArray" directly.  (See what Meda suggests.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794677/search-of-tableview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's up with that candy object?

You have an array of dictionnary, here's how you parse that:

Get the array:

```
NSArray *airportsArray = [json objectForKey:@"airports"];
```

Set the cell text:

```
[[cell textLabel] setText:[[airportsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"]];
[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[[airportsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"code"]];
```

or for better readability:

```
NSDictionary *airportAtIndex = [airportsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[[cell textLabel] setText:[airportAtIndex objectForKey:@"name"]];
[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[airportAtIndex objectForKey:@"code"]];
```

---

> Can you elaborate on how I could use sendAsynch to speed up the process?

Ok, first thing to note, you are **not** speeding up anything here, the reason why you feel the UI is lagging is because you run the network request on the main thread.

You can solve that problem by sending the request asynchrously, meaning in a background thread which will not freeze your User Interface.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    //this is where you perform the network request
    //You can fetch data, in your case get the JSON
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //in this block you want to manipulate the the User Interface
        //this is where you reload the tableView
        //or stop an activity indicator
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
});
```

**Things to note** (from [@HotLicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774394/data-from-json-parsing-straight-to-uitableview/22774745?noredirect=1#comment34753184_22774745))

> The app must be set up so that the TableView delegate will initially
>   (before the data is downloaded) report zero rows in the section. Then,
>   the reloadData op will cause the TableView to refresh the table. So
>   initially the table will be blank. One could fudge it slightly to
>   initially present a single cell saying "Data is loading" or anything that lets the user know >that an operation is in progress such as a UIActivityIndicator.

read up on [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I could use sendAsynch to speed up the process?

Comment: @user1828081 I expanded my answer

Comment: It should be noted that the app must be set up so that the TableView delegate will initially (before the data is downloaded) report zero rows in the section.  Then, the `reloadData` op will cause the TableView to refresh the table.  So initially the table will be blank.  One could fudge it slightly to initially present a single cell saying "Data is loading" or whatever.

Comment: @HotLicks yes exactly, I tried to show that in the comments, maybe its not so clear, I will edit a little more.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Sorry I have another question, my search function is not working (added to question) I assume I am missing something silly based on changing how the data is retrieved and displayed.

Comment: @user1828081 I suggest you to ask a new question, you can paste the link here in the comments ...

Answer (score 0):

You could take several approaches here in order to improve performance.

1. Start uploading and requesting airports as soon as possible in your application.
2. Complimentarily try to perform any heavy operation in a    background thread, dispatching an asynchronous operation to build you    array of Candy objects. You can use dispatch_async.
3. Another approach    would be to have some kind of custom logic to avoid creating the    whole array at a time… I would keep for example the JSON result    (NSMutableDictionary *routeRes) and would create Candy objects on    demand (every time a cell is required), keeping a trace of the last    Candy index read / created in the JSON  up to finish parsing all the    dictionary (then you can start reading your array of candies)…. That    could work if Candy creation logic is not too heavy (I think it's    not).