# Search of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a UITableView populated from a JSON data feed using an NSDictionary and NSArray and I am trying to search the UITableView data using this code, but it is not working some other related info based on how I set it up is in this question [Data from JSON Parsing straight to UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774394/data-from-json-parsing-straight-to-uitableview)

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{

// Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.

// Remove all objects from the filtered search array
[self.filteredCandyArray removeAllObjects];

// Filter the array using NSPredicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@",searchText];
NSArray *tempArray = [airportsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@" text %@", searchText);


filteredCandyArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
NSLog(@"NSLog %@", scope);
```

}
This is how the data is parsed

```
 NSString* path = @"https://api.flightstats.com/flex/airports/rest/v1/json/active?appId=532ca6af&appKey=50d6d3351e5953152b2688f10d10d276";


NSMutableURLRequest* _request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];

[_request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];


NSURLResponse *response = nil;

NSError *error = nil;


NSData* _connectionData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:_request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if(nil != error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
else
{

    NSMutableDictionary* json = nil;


    if(nil != _connectionData)
    {
        json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_connectionData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    }

    if (error || !json)
    {
        NSLog(@"Could not parse loaded json with error:%@", error);
    }
    else
    {



        routeRes = [json objectForKey:@"airports"];


         airportsArray = [json objectForKey:@"airports"];


                                   }

                                   _connectionData = nil;
                                   NSLog(@"connection done");
                                   }


NSLog(@" end array %@", candyArray);
// Initialize the filteredCandyArray with a capacity equal to the candyArray's capacity
filteredCandyArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[airportsArray count]];

// Reload the table
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

[[self tableView] reloadData];
```

Comment: off the top of my head, i could tell you how to filter the array not using predicates but a loop, if you don't mind that… but if you are bent on NSPredicate then you will need to give me 6 hours to finish to get home XD

Comment: I am not set on any method if you have a better method I am open to suggestions

Comment: i posted an answer with my thoughts :3 tell me if that works

Comment: try removing the "SELF." in predicate

Comment: also need to reload your tableView

Comment: removing self and reloading the tableview doesn't fix anything

Answer (score 0):

You can manually build the array via the build in loop methods,

```
NSMutableArray *filteredResults = [NSMutableArray new];
[airportsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
   if ([obj.name rangeOfString: searchText].location != NSNotFound) {
      [filteredResults addObject:obj];
   }
}];
self.filteredCandyArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:filteredResults];
```

You will need to replace the `id obj` with what ever object model you are using. For example if you had a plane model you might do `Plane *plane` in replace of `id obj`.

I might add how to use it via predicates later, but this should do what you request. You may view the enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: and arrayWithArray: methods in the NSArray documentation. rangeOfString: can be viewed in the NSString documentation.

-[NSArray Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

-[NSString Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Comment: I don't understand how this fits in with how I am accessing the data.  I added some code to my question to clarify how I am accessing the data,

Comment: do you want to sort the data via dictionary value, or do you want to search through the data and get specific results ?